# What are the random non-hexadecimal characters in a sequence of hexadecimals?

Tags: python-3.x, hex, rdf

I have a sequence of characters from an rdf file I opened with python.

```
...\x00\x08\x00\x00\x80\xdc\xc0\x00\t{\x00\x00\xa3p\x00\xe2\xc00...
```

I understand that these are hexadecimals. However, there are some that do not compute as hexadecimals, such as xa3p. What are they and why are they here. And what is \t? Tab?

Comment: That doesn't look like RDF to me (although there are many formats for rdf).  Perhaps it's turtle?  Turtle can have hex formatting like this. I think that I can still read it.  They all look like escape sequences mixed with some actual chars to me.  For instance 0xDC 0xC0 0x00 <tab> ***{*** 0x00 0x00 0xA3 ***p*** 0x00

Comment: Why is that p there? It throws off the hexadecimal converter when trying to convert (decode()) these sequences.

Comment: ```\x00``` is a hex code for a character. ```\t``` is a tab character. `p` is the letter `p`. The characters that can be clearly printed are printed, and the ones that cannot are given in another form.

Comment: But why is it there? what purpose does it serve?

Comment: `p` represents the character `p` (or, if you prefer, ASCII value 112). That's what purpose it serves.

Comment: 0xA3P does not compute as a hexadecimal. Why, what does it stand for?

Comment: 0xA3P is actually (unprintable 0xA3) + P.  You can NOT simply covert from hex.  You need to make a parser that is able to handle both ESCAPED CHARS (including HEX and \t) and STANDARD CHARS (like 'P').

Comment: As it turns out, I think this just a raw data file (rdf) coming out of a flight recorder. Apparently, extensions can have more than one format associated with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sequence is the following, with one line per represented character --

```
...
\x00
\x08
\x00
\x00
\x80
\xdc
\xc0
\x00
\t
{
\x00
\x00
\xa3
p
\x00
\xe2
\xc0
0
...
```

The `p` represents just that -- `p`.

It is preceded by an opening brace `{`, and 3 hex-escaped characters -- `\x00`, `\x00`, and `\xa3`.

It is followed by more hex-escaped characters.

We could probably tell you more, if you told us where this originated.

Comment: Thanks. That is what I concluded, but was not sure. I wonder why they throw in non-hex characters like that? This is  sensor data (oil pressure, I think) from a plane and I wanted to decode. It is rdf and some xml in the file. I think my next step is to decode to decimal then to ASCII.

Comment: This method of escaping non-printable chars is TOTALLY NORMAL.  This is (mostly) how strings in 'c' are formatted.